# SlickGrid C# Wrapper

Tags: c#, jquery, slickgrid

I found this tease of a code snippet:

http://codepaste.net/m6xsdi

```
slickGrid.AddColumn(
    Column.ForId("riga")
        .Named("Riga")
        .ForField("id")
        .WithEditorFunction("TextCellEditor")
        .WithSetValueHandler("updateItem")
        .WithBehavior(Column.Behavior.selectAndMove)
    ).AddColumn(
    Column.ForId("codice")
        .Named("Codice")
        .ForField("code")
        .WithEditorFunction("TextCellEditor")
        .WithSetValueHandler("updateItem")
        .WithBehavior(Column.Behavior.selectAndMove)
    );
```

It would be seriously terrific if there was a C# wrapper for SlickGrid that uses this fluent syntax, but I can't seem to find one.  Google comes up blank.  Is this some proprietary wrapper or am I just not looking in the right places?

Comment: Did you contact http://twitter.com/andreabalducci about this? He is online...

Comment: Fluent taken to extremes like this looks like code infected with a tape worm to me.

Comment: I prefer the term "syntactic masturbation" :)

Comment: Normally I would agree that this is over the top, but for ASP.NET MVC helper extensions I find it very readable and easy to write/maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was a working prototype (written at night ;) for a demo. Give me few days and I'll try to share the code on Codeplex or GitHub

Update: published http://lucilla.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/7a72573dc846
You'll find a sample mvc app and the helper prototype.. hope to publish the whole framework by the end of the year (if you wonder what the lib folder is for..)

Comment: That would be very awesome, thanks!  If you do post it I will likely contribute...

Comment: published with sample. actually working on the full framework.